# how to make custom gestures in ios

Tags: ios, gesture-recognition

is it possible to make custom gestures in iOS such as a zigzag, or a other lines types?
and can one link any action to a gesture. if you know an answer, or a link to an answer or exlanation, please share ... thanks

Comment: Doesn't sound like a programming question.. try posting to http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ok. i didn't even know about that. i guess this was just a question about whether something was possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to create your own gesture recognizers. You can look at [`this section`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW2) of the [*Event Handling Guide for iOS*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH1-SW1) which gives information as to how you can build your own custom subclass.

Comment: The last link "this" is broken.