# UIGestureRecognizer custom gestures

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

Is it possible to use UIGestureRecognizer to create detectors for custom gestures?

Suppose I want to detect gestures that identify letters like A, B, C, etc.

Can you guys point me broadly the way to do that?

thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/chrismiles/CMUnistrokeGestureRecognizer

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560796/how-to-make-custom-gestures-in-ios

Comment: 0xSina - make your comment an answer, so I can accept. It is the best answer so far. 

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1998968&seqNum=12). It should give you a good head start. It's from Erica Sadun's superb book [Core iOS 6 Developer's Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321884213)

Also, you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891625/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-custom-tickle-uigesturerecognizer)